# Writing between between characters in a text file?

Tags: python-2.7, fwrite

I have a module that i want to write into. I'm having several problems. One of which locating a string within the file. Currently I open the file, then use a for line in (filename), then do an if to determine if it finds a string, and all of that works. However before (it is commented out now) i tried to determine what position it was at using tell(). However this gave me an incorrect position, giving me 1118 i believe, instead of 660 something. So i determined the position manually to use seek.

However the second problem was, if i write to this file at the position in the file, it just overwrites all the data from thereon. I would want to insert the data instead of overwriting it.

Unless i insert a string equal in character length where i want the write to happen, it will just override most of the if statements and things like that below.

Is there any way to naively do this?

Here is the file i want to write into

```
# Filename: neo_usercurves.py
# Created By: Gregory Smith
# Description: A script containing a library of user created curves
# Purpose: A library to store names of all the user curves, and deletes curves
#   if specified to do so

import os
import maya.cmds as mc
import module_locator

my_path = module_locator.module_path()

def usercurve_lib(fbxfile=None, remove=None):
    """All control/curve objects created by user

    Keyword Arguments:
    fbxfile -- (string) name of fbx file to import
    remove -- (boolean) will remove an entry from the library and delete the
        associated fbx file
    """
    curves_dict = {
    #crvstart

    #crvend
    }
    if remove is None:
        return curves_dict
    elif not remove:
        try:
            name = mc.file(curves_dict[fbxfile], typ='FBX', i=1,
                iv=True, pmt=False)
            return name[0]
        except RuntimeError:
            return None
    else:
        try:
            os.remove('%s\%s.fbx' %(my_path, fbxfile))
            return '%s.fbx' %(fbxfile)
        except OSError:
            print 'File %s does not exist.' %(fbxfile)
            return None
```

This is the code below that i'm running in a module called neo_curves.py (this is not the complete code, and 'my_path' is just the path of the current directory neo_curves.py is being run in)

```
def create_entry(self, crv):    

    """Exports user curve to user data directory and adds entry into
        neo_usercurves.py

        Keyword Arguments:
        crv -- (PyNode) the object to export
        """
        # set settings
        mel.eval('FBXExportFileVersion "FBX201400"')
        mel.eval('FBXExportInputConnections -v 0')
        select(crv)
        mc.file('%s\userdat\%s.fbx' %(my_path, str(crv)), force=True, options='',
            typ='FBX export', pr=True, es=True)
        with open('%s\userdat\\neo_usercurves.py' %(my_path), 'r+') as usercrvs:
            for line in usercrvs:
                if line.strip() == '#crvstart':
                    #linepos = usercrvs.tell()
                    #linepos = int(linepos)
                    #usercrvs.seek(linepos, 0)
                    usercrvs.seek(665, 0)
                    usercrvs.write("\n    "+str(crv)+" : '%s\%s' %(my_path, '"+
                       str(crv)+".fbx')")
                    break
```

This will give me this result below:

```
# Filename: neo_usercurves.py
# Created By: Gregory Smith
# Description: A script containing a library of user created curves
# Purpose: A library to store names of all the user curves, and deletes curves
#   if specified to do so

import os
import maya.cmds as mc
import module_locator

my_path = module_locator.module_path()

def usercurve_lib(fbxfile=None, remove=None):
    """All control/curve objects created by user

    Keyword Arguments:
    fbxfile -- (string) name of fbx file to import
    remove -- (boolean) will remove an entry from the library and delete the
        associated fbx file
    """
    curves_dict = {
    #crvstart
    loop_crv : '%s\%s' %(my_path, 'loop_crv.fbx')     return curves_dict
    elif not remove:
        try:
            name = mc.file(curves_dict[fbxfile], typ='FBX', i=1,
                iv=True, pmt=False)
            return name[0]
        except RuntimeError:
            return None
    else:
        try:
            os.remove('%s\%s.fbx' %(my_path, fbxfile))
            return '%s.fbx' %(fbxfile)
        except OSError:
            print 'File %s does not exist.' %(fbxfile)
            return None
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/237416/why-can-we-not-insert-into-files-without-the-additional-writes-i-neither-mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: on most operating systems you can not insert into files without rewriting if the lengths are not the same.

Have a look at a long discussion here: [Why can we not insert into files without the additional writes? (I neither mean append, nor over-write)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/237416/why-can-we-not-insert-into-files-without-the-additional-writes-i-neither-mean)